# Cordova plugin iosrtc with HTML Button on top

Tags: ios, uiview, webrtc, cordova-plugins

Video calling is a feature in my Cordova app. It is working fine on android but I am having hard time in placing HTML buttons on top of UIView in IOS. The [documentation](https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/videoCSS.md) of plugin **cordova-plugin-iosrtc** says

> if the specified z-index is < 0 (that, is, the video elements will be positioned "behind" the web view), you should specify the  background-color as transparent so the video element will be seen through the web view.

In my HTML I have done below

- body { background-colour: transparent}
- html { background-colour: transparent}
- div.videoElementContainer{ background-colour: transparent; z-index:-1}
- div.buttonContainer{background-colour: transparent; z-index:99}
- videoElement{z-index:-1}

html reference structure is similer to below

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <div class="videoElementContainer"><video class="videoElement"></video></div>
      <div class="buttonContainer">...</div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

I referred below links to understand the solution but it could not achieve final goal.

https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/issues/38
https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/pull/179

I think I am near to solution it but something small is missing. Please someone help.

PS: Testing on IOS11.x

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the issue.....

I was doing everything right but instead of setting z-index as -1 of video element in CSS, I had to set z-index using jQuery at runtime.

Not sure if everyone does same but because in my app, "video" element is created at runtime so CSS properties might not be effectively taken by plugin. However I have no clue of internals of the plugin.

Anyways posting my solution as this may help someone in future. :)